# How to change phone screen view relative to game character

Tags: java, android

I'm not looking for a tutorial or anything, I just want a better understanding of how the view on the phone screen changes with respect to a character within a larger area. I made a crude picture to help my lack of articulation.

How would you move where the phone is viewing, I don't even know how to word it, my mind can't grasp the concept.

[image]

Comment: The red area is called a ViewPort. You adjust the position of the viewport with the character.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to articulate your question by using an example:

Lets say you are developing Mario bros. Now the entire level (black box in your picture) is when the level starts till mario reaches the castle (entry to next level).  The red box is whatever part of the level user can see on the screen. Now you want to know how to achieve this (right?).

Although I am not a game developer, but the simple logic that comes to mind is that you just have to move the level (background) image to left when the player moves right (actually player is at the same place) and if you want to generate a 2D depth effect then you'll have to use something known as [parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling)

Following [this link](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/) might help you in developing such games

Comment: Yeah I thought of moving the whole level rather than the smaller screen itself, but I still don't nkow how to go about doing that, also I have seen that tutorial, but I am not interested in using the library